# Skipping blank rows with fopen();

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I currently have some code like this:

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
                $i = 0;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
                    if($i > 0) {                            
                        $sql = "
                            insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D)
                            values ('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]')
                        ";

                        $stmt = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                   $i++;
                }
                fclose($handle);
```

This allows me to write to a certain table the contents of a CSV file, excluding the first row where all the names are. I want to be able to extract only the filled rows. How would I use so using this code?

Comment: fopen() just OPENS a files. neither it or fgetcsv() have anythign to do with skipping blank rows. that's up to YOU to write code to detect that. Plus, you are misusing the prepared statements and are STILL vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 1):

fgetcsv() returns an array with null for blank lines so you can do something like below.

```
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
                $i = 0;
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {

                    if (array(null) === $data) { // ignore blank lines
                       continue;
                    }

                    if($i > 0) {                            
                        $sql = "
                            insert into TABLE(A, B, C, D)
                            values ('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]')
                        ";

                        $stmt = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }
                   $i++;
                }
                fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

fgetcsv returns an array consisting of a single null if the rows are empty 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

so you should be able to do a check based on that.

```
if ($data[0]===null) 
{ 
    continue;
}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), `fgetcsv` will return an array consisting of a single `null`  value for empty rows, so you should be able to test the return value against that and skip blank lines that way.

The following example code will skip processing blank lines. Note that I have changed the file and removed some other logic to make it more easily testable.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("LocalInput.txt", "r");
$i = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
    if($data== array(null)) continue;
    var_dump($data);
    $i++;
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```